# If the roots of $ax^2+bx+c=0$ are infinite, then $a=b=0$. Doesn't this also make $c=0$?

Tags: polynomials, roots, quadratics

In the standard form of a quadratic equation: $$ax^2 + bx +c = 0$$ I have read that for both roots to be infinite, $a$ and $b$ should be zero. But if that is the case than quadratic equation reduces to $c = 0$. But it is given that $c$ is not equal to zero.

So, how to solve this contradiction?

Comment: You should first define what it means for $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$ to "have an infinite root." It's a very nontrivial, unclear thing you're asking us as a result.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Perhaps this is closely related to the derivation of the asymptote equations for a hyperbola?

Comment: It's not clear to me what's meant here, but note: If $ax^2+bx+c=0$, then $a+by+cy^2=0$ where $y:=1/x$. If $\infty$ is (somehow) a double-root of the first equation, then $0$ "should be" a double-root of the second equation.

Comment: @sai-kartik: The phrase [infinite root](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22quadratic+equation%22+%22infinite+root%22&tbm=bks) was extremely common in older (primarily before 1900) algebra texts, but the OP should be aware that, when using it now, a definition should be included.

Comment: @Blue what about $b=0$ ?

Comment: @sai-kartik: For $y=0$ to be a *double*-root of $a+by+cy^2=0$, we must have $a=b=0$.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I agree. I just made a speculation because that was the most recent topic I have studied while I encountered the term "infinite root"

Comment: @sai-kartik: Oops, I see that you're from India, so (given that I know something of the mathematics covered in pre-college there) I guess you DO know about infinite roots!

Comment: @EeveeTrainer an infinite root is a root where $x=\infty$ or $x=-\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Converting comment to answer.)

We have, generally,
$$ ax^2+bx+c=0 \qquad\iff\qquad a + b y + c y^2 = 0$$
where $y:=1/x$ makes sense. It is a not-entirely-unreasonable interpretation that, if the $x$-equation has two "infinite" roots of $x=(\pm)\infty$, then the $y$-equation has a *double-root* of $y=0$. Thus, the $y$-equation should factor as $c(y-0)(y-0)=0$, so that $a=b=0$.

Answer (score 1):

> I have read that for both roots to be infinite, $a$ and $b$ should be zero. But if that is the case then the quadratic equation reduces to $c=0$.

Substituting $0$ for $a$ and $b$ doesn't eliminate the $x$ and $x^2$ terms when you're dealing with hyperreal numbers (infinite quantities), because $0$ times an infinite value is not zero.  Whenever you replace $0x$ or $0x^2$ with $0$, you are making the assumption that you are only dealing with finite values of $x$.

Comment: I notice that when I type the number zero, it is replaced by the letter "o" after I click "post".  Why is that?

Comment: Your mathematical notation is being rendered in a "plain text" font that evidently makes the numeral zero look like the letter oh. To improve the appearance of that notation (and to make proper-looking exponents and whatnot), you should type your mathematics using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/409). In the simplest instance, this means simply wrapping expressions in dollar signs (`$...$`). Compare 0x^2 (given by `0x^2`) and $0x^2$ (given by `$0x^2$`).

Comment: @Blue thank you.  I’ve been finding it very useful.